# Could we view a list of patents filed by an attorney on USPTO website?

Tags: uspto, filing, attorney, lawyers

Is this possible? I'm looking to hire attorneys who are majoring in certain fields.

Comment: The searchable information on the face of the patent can be the  actual practitioner or could be the name of a firm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about using the USPTO site, but for sure you can do this on [Lens.org](https://www.lens.org/lens/search/patent/structured). See the default search below. Lens is generally free and you can use it without creating an account. You get some helpful features if you register which is also free.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks abundant!